# How to Save a Node Object reached from another Server?

Tags: nodes

I'm implementing the Node Object passing one Site to another. I am now able to send the `$node` object across the sites. But the problem now again is i can NOT do `node_save($node)` simply.

- I can NOT get the object as Drupal valid $node

Comment: Why you cannot save ? What is the error thrown or did you check watchdogs reports?

Comment: NO LOG also is showing totally. I even added additional codes to insert into custom table. (as i said in my question). These data goes into Table. But `node_save` is totally not working.

Answer (score 0):

Are you working on a multilingual site? 
Trying to save a node that have different language than expected, for example "it" instead of "und" fails, event if the node is cloned from another site in which is working well.

You could also try to 
unset($node->nid) 
unset($node->vid)

they are not required in order to create a new node.

Comment: Hi, see in my question please. I have `unset` these 2 fields also. And i'm using the same language `und` only. Please suggest more :(

Comment: Usually you can't save if the validation on one or more fields fails. I would try unsetting more fields until the node saves, than add one by one the fields to understand which one fails. A check between the code that you are trying to save in that field and the code present inside a node created by interface should do the rest of the work.

Comment: Ok now i see what you mean. But, as i mentioned above, when i `serialized` save it into the Database (as the Text Field), there are complete data (nothing wrong in it) I mean, data getting is having no lost inside :(